# VBA: Array cell reference Mismatch error

Tags: vba, excel, excel-web-query

**UPDATED 3/30**

**So I adjusted the code and it runs error free now but the issue is that it does not pull the correct data. X basically starts with cell(X,1) and goes on from there. How do I link X to the selected listbox options in the array?**

***OLD Message:***
I have a userform that allows for multi-select of Countries and also Questions about that specific country. These are stored in arrCountries & arrQuestion respectively. This then feeds to my main sub which calls for a Web Query Import from the CIA World Factbook site. I keep however getting a mismatch error that I cannot seem to sort out how to get around:

[image: Mismatch Error in Yellow]

If I had to guess it is because when I am filling the array from the listbox's it is just adding a string and not the cell reference that the string is located at (or I am completely wrong).

My worksheet has only 1 sheet when started called Countries and the Column A is the URL and Column B is the Country name. I have Defined Public arrCountry(), Public arrQuestion(), and Public X as variant.

Code here:

Userform Code when click okay:

```
'Handles when the user clicks okay
Private Sub cbOkay_Click()
    'Me.Hide
'Capture ticker selection(s) from list box.
Dim cI As Long
Dim cX As Long
Dim qI As Long
Dim qX As Long

'Stores the Countries selected into an array
If lbCountries.ListIndex <> -1 Then
    For cI = 0 To lbCountries.ListCount - 1
        If lbCountries.Selected(cI) Then
            ReDim Preserve arrCountry(cX)
            arrCountry(cX) = lbCountries.List(cI)
            cX = cX + 1
        End If
    Next cI
End If

If cX = 0 Then MsgBox "Please select at least one country to analyse."
'MsgBox Join(arrCountry, vbCrLf)

'Stores the Questions selected into an array
If lbQuestions.ListIndex <> -1 Then
    For qI = 0 To lbQuestions.ListCount - 1
        If lbQuestions.Selected(qI) Then
            ReDim Preserve arrQuestion(qX)
            arrQuestion(qX) = lbQuestions.List(qI)
            qX = qX + 1
        End If
    Next qI
End If

If qX = 0 Then MsgBox "Please select at least one question to analyse."

'MsgBox Join(arrQuestion, vbCrLf)

'Unload the form
Unload Me

cancel = False
End Sub
```

The message boxes return the correctly selected Listbox items so I know they are being stored correctly.

The WebQuery Code I am getting the error on:

**UPDATED CODE:**

So I added a loop counter:

```
Sub webQueryimport(arrCountry())

Dim mystr As String
Dim X As Integer
Dim selected As Variant

For Each selected In arrCountry
    X = X + 1
Worksheets("Countries").Select
Worksheets("Countries").Activate
     mystr = Cells(X, 1)
     Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = selected

        With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=mystr, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
            .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage 'this tells VBA what to select and import
            .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone 'this turns off web formatting, otherwise text is various sizes
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False 'if commented out, doesn't add any data
        End With
Next selected

End Sub
```

Again, now that loop works and will import but it always starts with the A1 no matter what is selected in the listbox and in arrCountries

Any thoughts/assistance would be great!

Comment: are you trying to assign the entire `X` array as a row number in `Cells(X, 1)` ? I think you meant to use `Cells(X(I), 1)`

Comment: @ShaiRado - I was originally thinking that you were right, but I doubt that `X(I)` is a numeric value - so I suspect that the OP will really need to do a `Find` or something.  Not sure.  Too late in the afternoon for me to be thinking straight.

Comment: or if just referencing the array not `X(I)` or `X(I,1)` if there are more then one dimension. You'll also have issues when naming the worksheet as again you're trying to set the name to the entire array

Comment: @ShaiRado

Thank you for the thoughts, some clarifications:

1) So the B1 on the worksheet says Afghanistan, B2 says cuba, etc. with Cells(X, 1)  I was hoping to take the users selection from the Listbox on the Userform and loop through the countries selected on the Worksheet Countries and then get their corresponding URL link which is in cell A1, A2 etc.

2) You are correct, the array: arrCountry is just capturing the string input from the Listbox, is there a way to also capture its cell location?

3) only 1 dimension, which might be my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it:

```
Sub webQueryimport(arrCountry())

Dim mystr As String
Dim X As Integer
Dim rng As Range
Dim selected As Variant

Set rng = Range("B1")

For Each selected In arrCountry()
    For X = 1 To 5 'rng.Offset(0, 0).End(xlDown).Rows.count
        Worksheets("Countries").Select
        Worksheets("Countries").Activate

        If Cells(X, 2).Value = selected Then
            mystr = Cells(X, 1).Value
            Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = selected

            With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=mystr, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
                .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage 'this tells VBA what to select and import
                .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone 'this turns off web formatting, otherwise text is various sizes
                .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False 'if commented out, doesn't add any data
            End With
        End If
      Next X
    Next selected
End Sub
```

I needed to add in a counter and the IF statement to check to see if the value in the array matched the cell value in the sheet and then return the appropriate cell for the import.